# iphone won't show up on PC

Tags: windows-7, usb, iphone

When I attach my iPhone 4S to my Dell laptop running Windows 7, using USB cord, the computer "pings" to indicate that the phone is connected, but it doesn't show up visually as an external device.

I've rebooted... checked the Apple External Device Support and App Support programs - they are installed and operating... don't know what to do next.

One interesting (to me) thing is that while the phone is plugged into the computer, it's charging! Is that normal? Or is it symptomatic of something related to not being able to see the device?

I read one website which said that my virus protection program might be causing this -- anyone concur? I have AVG Free and I don't really want to uninstall it unless I'm convinced that's where the problem lies.

Any suggestions appreciated!!

Comment: Does your phone show the trust computer dialog?  Is your phone unlocked (i.e. not on the lock screen)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the cord that came with your computer? If you're using a replacement cord or one for an older phone it might not be compatible with the 4S.

AVG is not the problem - if you've got the right cord then you should go to control panel & "Add a Device" - this will lead you through the troubleshooting process if it still cannot find the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and it appears I once accidentally told the iPhone to not trust the PC.

[This Gihosoft article](https://www.gihosoft.com/hot-topics/how-to-reset-trust-this-computer-iphone.html) has a good solution halfway down, or copied below.  This worked for me:

```
1. On iPhone, go to Settings > General > Reset.
2. Choose Reset All Settings. The iPhone will restart.
```

Note this will in fact reset all phone settings (including wallpapers), but no information, data, or files are lost or changed.

```
3. Connect iPhone to the computer
4. Disconnect and reconnect iPhone to computer. Tap “Trust” or "accept" from the prompt.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the USB driver. Try updating the Apple Mobile Device USB driver.
Open the Device Manager on your Windows.
Locate the Apple Mobile Device USB Device, right-click on it and select Update driver.